# An app exclusively for windows phone 7.1

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1

I am creating two versions of an app - for Windows phone 7.1 users and another for Windows phone 8 users. Since all windows phone 7.1 apps work on windows phone 8, the Windows phone 8 user sees two version of the same app. How can I deploy the 7.1 app so that it remains exclusively available for Windows phone 7.1 users only? This will ensure that Windows phone 8 users will not see two versions of the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should't publish two distinct apps. Publish only one application, and the devcenter allows you to publish a distinct version for Windows Phone 7.1 and 8. Each user will automatically get the appropriate version depending on which OS he's using.

Comment: thanks, I have tried it. once the app is published, I will do the testing.